# Can't login to Salesforce sandbox using SalesforceSharp—InvalidGrant

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, salesforce, salesforcesharp

When I try to login to my sandbox using SalesforceSharp, I'm getting the following error message:

```
InvalidGrant: Authentication Failure
```

Here's what I've done:

- Pass in the username, password, clientId, and clientSecret (SalesforceSharp)
- Append my security token to the end of my password (SalesforceSharp)
- Set "Relax IP Restrictions" on the connected app that I created for API access (Salesforce UI)
- Set "All users may self-authorize" (Salesforce UI)
- Set `authFlow.TokenRequestEndpointUrl = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";` instead of the default `login.salesforce.com...` (after the default failed) (SalesforceSharp)

Any ideas?